# Clean Way to assign values to object

Tags: angular, typescript, object

it's a bit of unusual question but I wanted to have your opinions on that.

I have an interface where I define the structure of the object.

I create then a variable of type of this interface.

Now I want to be able to assign values to it.

I do it in the ngOnInit method of the component.

My question, is there a better or cleaner way to assign values to the object, for example separately in other function.

I know usually the data lies in the backend and I get the information from the service which communicates with an endpoint from the backend.

But here I can not do it.

```
export interface Stat {
  name: string;
  color: string;
  min: number;

}
```

component

```
stat: Stat;

ngOnInit() {
    this.stat = {
      name: "name1",
      color: "#D5001C",
      min: 1,
    };

  }
```

Opinions on that are very appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit unclear.

From what I understood, you have variable of type `Stat` and you wish to assign it a value that you fetch from a webservice.

If so, you can just use RxJS

```js
class Whatever {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  ...

  stat$ = this.httpClient.get<Stat>('/api/endpoint/here')
    .pipe(take(1));
}
```

You should have an observable in `stat$`.

If you need it in the template, then:

```html
<div *ngIf="(stat$ | async) as stat">
  <div>{{ stat.name }}</div>
  <div>{{ stat.color }}</div>
  <div>{{ stat.min }}</div>
</div>
```